# How can I remove an Asset in a Dart-Transformer

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I know there is Barback#removeSources (https://goo.gl/CNRcxg) but how the heck can I use this in a transformer????

Answer (score 1):

Found it...

```
class CleanupTransformer extends Transformer implements LazyTransformer {

    CleanupTransformer.asPlugin();

    Future<bool> isPrimary(final AssetId id) async {
        return id.path.startsWith("lib/_templates/");
    }

    Future apply(final Transform transform) async => transform.consumePrimary();

    @override
    void declareOutputs(final DeclaringTransform transform) {  }
}
```

This sample removes everything in /lib/_templates/